# Jquery overruling css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jquery to make a fixed-position navigation bar fade to `.5` opacity as it slides down. That works, but I also want to make the bar come back to opacity 1 if it's moused over.  I tried the CSS `:hover`, but it didn't work.
HTML:

```
 <div id="top-links-bar"> 
<span class="top-link link-bar-link dropdown-opener" id="learn">Learn <span class="caret"></span></span> 
<a style="color:blue;" style="position:relative; right:50px; top:20px;"><span class="top-link link-bar-link" id="login-" >Login <span class="caret"></span></span></a>
     <a style="color:blue;" style="position:relative; right:100px; top:20px;"><span class="top-link link-bar-link" id="create-account"  >Create an Account</span></a>

    </div>
    <div id="learn-dropdown" class="dropdown" style="font-weight:bold;">
         content
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown" id="login">
        Username: <input type="text"><br>
        Password: <input type="password">
        </div>
        </body>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {

    $('.dropdown').hide();

    $('#learn').click(function () {
        $('#learn-dropdown').toggle().css('z-index', '200');
        $('#login').slideUp().css('z-index','0');
    });
    $('#login-').click(function(){
        $('#login').toggle().css('z-index', '200');
        $('#learn-dropdown').slideUp().css('z-index','0');       
    });

   /* $('body div:not(#top-links-bar)').click(function () {
        $('.dropdown').hide();
    });*/





    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 40) {
            $('#top-links-bar').stop().fadeTo('fast', .5);
        } else {
            $('#top-links-bar').stop().fadeTo('fast', 1);
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
    #top-links-bar {
        padding:30px;
        border:0px solid black;
        background: linear-gradient(gray, white);
        position:fixed;
        top:0px;
        width:100%;
        z-index:20;
        float:none;
        clear:none;
    }
/*THIS IS WHAT'S NOT WORKING*/
    #top-links-bar:hover {
        opacity:1;
    }
    .caret {
        border-left:5px solid transparent;
        border-right:5px solid transparent;
        border-top:5px solid black;
        display:inline-block;
        margin-top:5px;
        vertical-align:middle;
        transition:all 2s;
    }
    .caret:hover {
        border-top:5px solid green;
        cursor:pointer
    }
    .top-link {
        font-family:romeral;
        color:#1851EE;
        padding:30px;
        transition:color 2s, background 2s;
    }
    .top-link:hover {
        color:gray;
        background:linear-gradient(white, gray);
        cursor:pointer;
        border-left:1px solid black;
        border-right:1px solid black;
    }
    a {
        color:inherit;
    }
    .dropdown {
        font-family:champagnelimo;
        background:linear-gradient(gray, green);
        z-index:200;
        height:150px;
        width:100%;
        padding:50px;
        border:4px solid gray;
        position:fixed;
        top:100px;
    }
    ul li:visited {
        color:blue;
    }
    .snippet {
        font: bold 12pt/14pt josefin;
    }
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/a1h8d0cb/8/)

Comment: That's because jQuery sets the `opacity` style directly on the element (i.e. _inline_) and that takes precedence over rules defined in CSS files (and also in `<style>` blocks).

Comment: Should I use jquery `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` functions, then?

Comment: Either that, or use `!imporant` as A.B. suggests.

Comment: Please post a complete code example *In your question*. You saw the warning when linking to jsFiddle, yet you chose to try and sidestep it by highlighting a couple of words as code. If jsFiddle ever goes away or is inaccessible, then your question will lose all value to future visitors.

Comment: Instead of changing the opacity directly, you can add/remove a css class with JQuery. And handle the fade effect with css transitions.

Comment: @j08691, I didn't see any warning when linking to jsfiddle. I will try to avoid that in the future, though

Comment: I also want to know another thing. the commented part in the js is supposed to make a click anywhere on the screen - besides the bar or the dropdowns - hide the dropdowns. I tried using an asterisk, but that didn't work

Comment: @yak613 either edit the question or to get quick answer, ask separate question for that part. comments will not be read by many people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use !important, as jquery changes the css in `inline style` attribute so normal css wont apply becuase of precedence, refer to below list of precedence to understand the workings

use this css for hover

```
#top-links-bar:hover {
    opacity:1 !important;;
}
```

see [fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a1h8d0cb/9/)

Css order of precedence is

1. **!important**
2. **Inline**
3. **Internal**
4. **External**